# Reading int and strings arrays in MATLAB from a C-DLL function

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, dll, shared-libraries

I'm trying to read int and strings arrays in MATLAB of the following function:

```
int DLLEXPORT getdata(int *index, char *id[])
```

In C I just do the following code and it works:

```
int count;       
int *index = calloc(MAXLINE, sizeof(int));
char **id = calloc(MAXLINE, sizeof(char*));

for (for i = 0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)                      
       id[i] = malloc(MAXID);

errcode = getdata(index, id);
```

In MATLAB I'm trying the following code with no luck:

```
errorcode = libpointer('int32');
index = libpointer('int32Ptr');
id = libpointer('stringPtrPtr');

[errorcode, index, id] = calllib('mylib','getdata', index, id);
```

I've already tried to initialize the libpointers and I got the same message "Segmentation violation detected". Someone could help me?

Comment: Paulo, did you check my suggestions? Or you still have problems with your shared library?

Comment: @angainor I've tried your suggestions but with no luck. I've isolated the problem and spotted something wrong to initialize the array of strings. I changed my DLL to give me a concatenated string that I split after. Anyway, thank you for your help :).

Comment: That is strange. I have checked with the function I wrote that the parameters are passed correctly. I used a cell of strings (char *ptr[] in C), and I got correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to initialize your pointers - right now they point to nowhere, they are initialized to 0. This most likely causes the segfault. If you have tried to initialize them, you must have done it wrong. Try sth. like this

```
index = libpointer('int32Ptr', [1 2 3 4]);
id = libpointer('stringPtrPtr', {'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf'});
```

You can also pass normal matlab arrays instead of making a libpointer:

```
[errorcode, index, id] = calllib('mylib','getdata', [1 2 3 4], {'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf'});
```

You can find information about matlab types and the corresponding native types [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-arguments-to-shared-library-functions.html#bqgcbv0-1).

**Edit** Here is a simple shared library function that takes your input (your comments below) and prints one string on the screen using mexPrintf

```
#include <string.h>
#include <mex.h>
void testfun(int *index, char* id[]){
  int idx0  = index[0];
  mexPrintf("printing string %d: id[0] %s\n", idx0, id[idx0]);
}
```

The function uses the first value from integer array (index[0] in your case) to print the specified string from an array of strings (id[index[0]]). The output is

```
printing string 0: id[0] 01234567890123456789012345678901
```

So it works, try it. Remember you must also provide the corresponding header file to loadlibrary!

If you can execute the above correctly, most likely the data you supply to getdata is wrong and you must be getting a segfault somewhere there. Maybe you modify the input parameters in some way? e.g. create non-NULL terminated strings?

Comment: I tried to initialize libpointers as your answer but the problem still remains. About your second comment, actually the function declaration was wrong. I've already correct it.

Comment: @PauloFracasso Can you post complete code then? It will be easier to find the problem. Maybe you pass incorrect data to your function?

Comment: @angainorr The code is very complex, with thousand of lines and dozen of files. I can send you the header file and the DLL. Just let me know how I can do it.

Comment: @PauloFracasso I more meant the code with which you initialize the pointers you pass to the library call. I just gave you an example.

Comment: @angainorr I initialize the pointers as: `MAX_SIZE = 13;` `str_32 = {'01234567890123456789012345678901'};` `for i=1:MAX_SIZE` `str_ini(1,i) = str_32` `end`  `index = libpointer('int32Ptr',zeros(1,MAX_SIZE));` `id = libpointer('stringPtrPtr',str_ini);`